# Can't boot ISO file from custom grub menuentry

Tags: linux, grub2

I was attempting to boot an ISO file without a usb, so I added a grub menuentry and when I booted into it, it always just shows a **completely** black screen, I even tried `grml-rescueboot` but still the same result. I even made sure the ISO file is still working using a virtual machine and it is.

any ideas?

**EDIT**

I've used an application called `grub customizer` to create the menuentry that points to `xubuntu` here it is:

```bash
menuentry "Xubuntu 20.04 (Updated)"{
    set root='(hd0,2)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root b53c5bd9-24df-4727-bb68-77b3ec344f92
    loopback loop /home/mahmoud/Downloads/xubuntu/xubuntu-20.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso
    linux (loop)/casper/vmlinuz boot=casper iso-scan/filename=/home/mahmoud/Downloads/xubuntu/xubuntu-20.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso quiet splash locale=en_US bootkbd=us console-setup/layoutcode=us noeject --
    initrd (loop)/casper/initrd.lz
}
```

thanks.

Comment: And the grub menuentry is...?

Comment: @ajgringo619 it points to a fedora iso file, and I also tried debian and lubuntu, same results.

Comment: Without seeing the actual menuentry you created, I can't help you. Please add to your question.

Comment: @ajgringo619 I added the menuentry take a look.

Comment: If you remove `quiet splash` from the kernel parameters, perhaps you see something.

Comment: I only use toram parameter, not quiet splash. And back when I still had a nVidia card I also had to use nomodeset parameter. What video card/chip do you have? I also prefer to use a set isofile=  variable and use that like these examples. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/ISOBoot/Examples But find getting path & drive correct is often one of the larger issues, particularly if more than one drive.

Comment: @berndbausch hello sorry for the late response I overslept, sadly removing the option didn't change anything,

Comment: @oldfred yes! I have an nvidia card, can you please tell me where to place the "nomodeset" option?

Comment: Replace the quiet splash on linux line with nomodeset. If you have lots of RAM, enough to hold entire ISO, then toram can speed things up somewhat as then it is entirely copied into RAM initially.

Comment: @oldfred thanks, the question is resolved, I can now boot to xubuntu, however when I try to install xubuntu on first looks it seems like its stuck on "detecting file system..." is that an unrelated issue?

Comment: Yes. Many questions & answers to that issue. Most related to UEFI using Intel RST or RAID for drive or Windows fast startup on. Some other brands/models have other UEFI setting that may lock or protect system and need changing. Best to ask new question & include brand/model system. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation  I have had ISO auto mount itself to a partition and create issues, best not to install to same drive as ISO is on.

Comment: @oldfred alright I'll ask another question if I don't get it resolved myself, thanks again. :)

Comment: if installing to same drive, open terminal & check mounts `mount`. If you have used toram, so ISO all in RAM, you can manually unmount a conflict. `sudo umount -lrf /isodevice`

Comment: I rolled back your edit where you added a solution to the question text.  I also took the solution you gave there and provided it as a "community wiki" answer (as you have not been around for a long time).

Answer (score 1):

From the original user:

I found a solution to my problem, after some searching I figured out I just had to add this line at the top of the menu entry:

```
rmmod tmp
```

Thanks.

---

Edit by sudodus: I think there is a typing error in the solution by the original user: it should be `tpm` (not `tmp`).

```
rmmod tpm
```

The following link to the 'Ubuntu help pages' contains examples of booting Ubuntu 20.04 iso files via grub: [Manually editing the GRUB files](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/ISOBoot#Manually_editing_the_GRUB_files). Xubuntu is an Ubuntu community flavour, and the boot structure is the same as in Ubuntu.

> Menuentry Example
>
> The following is an example GRUB menuentry for Ubuntu 12.04's 64-bit
> ISO, located in the user's Downloads folder of sda5.
>
> ...
>
> For Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and booting with grub 2.04
>
> Generally, when booting with '''grub 2.04''' in UEFI mode you need an
> extra command to remove `tpm`.
>
> ```
> menuentry "Ubuntu 20.04 ISO" {
>    set isofile="/home/<username>/Downloads/ubuntu-20.04-desktop-amd64.iso"
>    # or set isofile="/<username>/Downloads/ubuntu-20.04-desktop-amd64.iso"
>    # if you use a single partition for your $HOME
>    rmmod tpm
>    loopback loop (hd0,5)$isofile
>    linux (loop)/casper/vmlinuz boot=casper iso-scan/filename=$isofile noprompt noeject
>    initrd (loop)/casper/initrd
> }
> ```